# Is there a word/adverb that describes that "something was done which shouldn't have been done"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Is there a word for "something was done which shouldn't have been done" in the English language?

For example, let's say a soldier fires a shot even though his commander ordered a cease fire, you could say:
"The soldier erroneously/fallaciously fired a shot, despite the order of his superior officer."

Is there a better word for erroneously/fallaciously in this context?
Something that places more emphasis on the fact that it was an action that was performed by the subject which [under general consensus] was explicitly advised against or even prohibited to be performed by the subject.

Erroneously/fallaciously places more emphasis on that it was "wrong", but I'm looking for something else here...

Comment: Because it's an adverb, it could be anything. The soldier *wrongly* fired a shot, or *wildly, wantonly, pig-headedly...* You say you're looking for something else, but what? Please see the checklist in the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for help with this sort of question.

Comment: Petrus, that looks more a Question for your thesaurus, dictionary or search engine. Start with synonyms for *erroneous* or *fallacious*.
An easy fit for your soldier firing against orders would be *wrongly*, covering both the accidental or mistaken ideas in *erroneously/fallaciously* and the possibility of criminal or malicious intent.
Speaking of *… the action being performed by the subject…* gets complex enough to obscure the issue, as does emphasising the action being against explicit advise, or prohibited.

Comment: We idiomatically use *on purpose* in situations that someone willfully committed a wrong, as opposed to an accidental occurrence. So, you may be wanting *willfully*, *purposely*, *deliberately*, or something of that ilk.

Comment: If it wasn't intentional, you could say *inadvertently*.

Comment: @Barmar inadvertently or accidentally might work in this case. What I'm trying to get at here is to describe something that someone did even though "we" told him/her not to do it. There is no presumption regarding whether this was done deliberately or wilfully, it should only carry the notion that something wrong was done (against orders/directives).

Comment: Sorry for expressing myself so vaguely, it's hard for me to exactly describe what I'm looking for, probably because English isn't my native language and my vocabulary is not as rich as it once was.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a word for this that doesn't include some suggestion of whether or not it was deliberate. I think we would just leave out the adverb there, as the fact that it's contrary to orders is stated in the clause that begins with "despite".

Comment: +10 to @Barmar if I could. It doesn't satisfy your request for a word but it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll throw my hat into the ring with ***inexplicably***.

> The soldier ***inexplicably*** fired a shot, despite the order of his superior officer.

This phrasing leaves the issue of *right* and *wrong* open, since the reasons for the action are unexplained.

> In a way that cannot be explained or accounted for.
>   • ‘*many crucial documents had **inexplicably** disappeared*’
>   • ‘*somehow, **inexplicably**, I was back where I had begun*’
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inexplicably)</sub>